# MVC 3, EF4 Custom Remote Validation with separate model assembly project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have setup an MVC3 EF4 project with Model and the Repository broken off in to separate assembly projects.  The basic validation for a required property etc. works fine, but if i need to do any remote validation say to check if a user is already in a group, etc.  The remote validation does not recognize the controller within the Model project.

```
[Remote("IsUID_Available", "Validation")]
```

When I try to add a reference to the main project inside the Model project it says it would cause a circular dependency and doesn't allow it to be added.

Do I need to move my Models out the separate assembly and into the main project or is there another way to do remote validation with the Models being in a separate assembly.

Also what is the best practice here.  I've read several articles that say putting the models in a separate assembly is the best practice but if you can't use half the validation functionality of MVC what is the point.  I've also noticed most of the Microsoft MVC samples show the models just in the main project and not broken off into an assembly.

Comment: You write "does not recognize the controller within the Model project.", why have you put the controller in the Model assembly?

Comment: the controller isn't in the Model assembly, but the controller would need to be specified in the Remote attribute on the model, but the Model project has no knowledge of it and a reference to it can not be added.  So it just seems like you cant use the Remote validation attributes on a model in a separate assembly.

Comment: You should consider making view models, and putting the attributes on them. Then you can have your business/model assembly, and put the view models in the web assembly (where they belong, with the controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this wasn't an issue after all.  Remote validation can be used as specified in the code above with the model in a separate assembly.

It was ReSharper that was giving an error in visual studio that the controller was unknown and marking it with the red underline but when actually compiled and tested the remote validation works.